# Qt: adding external library to Android device (Windows version)

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am currently working on application for mobile devices with Android on board and I am in need to use of 3rd party library (FFTW). Everything works fine on my PC, but I cannot make it work on the tablet.
I don't have any experience in using Android development tools, hence I'm using Qt on my Windows OS.
Every answer I found was Linux-releated or was assuming that it is library created by user.
So here is the question: Is there a simple way to add (or rather port) FFTW libraries to format recognized by android application?

Comment: did you try to compile FFTW libraries for Android?

Comment: Yes, I did, however every scrap of tip I find is designed for Linux or MacOS (like [this](http://blog.jimjh.com/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-2.html) ).
As I said, I'm working on Windows 10, and those tips are not helping me.